# dns probe finished nxdomain error

Tags: domain-name-system

i am using Vultr's DNS services: https://vultr.com

I have correctly set up all the records on domain: https://sportusbet.com

But from time to time i am getting the following error:

```
dns probe finished nxdomain
```

Site is not responding to chrome, firefox etc. Only dns cache flushing helps.

It is problem with Vultr's DNS services?